# Limit $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac1{\ln(x+1)}-\frac1x$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, logarithms

The limit is

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac1{\ln(x+1)}-\frac1x$$

The problem is I don't know if I can calculate it normally like with a change of variables or not. Keep in mind that I'm not allowed to use L'Hôpital's rule nor the $\mathcal O$-notation.

Comment: Why is it that no one can ever use  L'Hôpital?

Comment: Because i don't have it in my math program

Comment: @David: when I took calculus a million years ago, the explicit position of the teachers was that it was preferable to learn to do limits by using Taylor, to get a feeling for estimates; I tend to agree with this position. You are allowed to use L'Hôpital, but you were then required to give a full proof.

Comment: @Martin: many times, though, L'Hôpital amounts to the definition of the derivative of some function or other. To use, e.g., $\left|\frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}-\cos(x)\right|\to 0$ isn't the same as proving L'Hôpital.

Comment: @Jonathan: but that would have been allowed, and I wouldn't call that "L'Hôpital". What was strongly discouraged was the blind use of replacing quotients by their derivatives in order to find the limit.

Comment: @MartinArgerami well that I strongly agree with. Blind application of any theorem, really, but L'Hôpital's does tend to 'gather a following' of that sort.

Comment: Exactly. Actually, my biggest complaint about calculus these days is that in most universities it is perfectly possible to go through the calculus stream with very high grades and without having the slightest idea of what a derivative or an integral is. Learning recipes is enough.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\ln(x+1)}-\frac1x=\lim_{x\to1}\frac1{\ln(x)}-\frac1{x-1}=L$$
since $x\to1$ is equivalent to $x^2\to1$, we can write
$$L=\lim_{x\to1}\frac1{\ln(x^2)}-\frac1{x^2-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac1{2\ln(x)}+\frac12\left(\frac1{x+1}-\frac1{x-1}\right)=\frac12L+\lim_{x\to1}\frac12\frac1{x+1}=\frac12L+\frac14$$
Hence, $L=\frac12L+\frac14$ and $L=\frac12$.

Comment: This is a very nice method, but assumes the existence of the limit $L$.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know about the geometric series and Taylor's theorem to integrate them, but you might not. I apologize if you don't, as this will not be of much use.

We have
$$
\frac 1{\log(x+1)} - \frac 1x = \frac{x-\log(x+1)}{x \log(x+1)} = \frac{1 - \frac{\log(x+1)}{x}}{\log(x+1)}.
$$
Now
$$
\frac 1{1+x} = \frac 1{1-(-x)} = \sum_{n \ge 0} (-x)^n, 
$$
hence
$$
\log(x+1) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{-(-x)^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+1}}{n+1} = x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 - \cdots.
$$
Also,
$$
\frac{\log(x+1)}{x} = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n+1},
$$
hence
$$
1 - \frac{\log(x+1)}x = \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^n}{n+1} = \frac x2 - \frac{x^2}3 + \frac{x^3}4 - \cdots.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{\log(x+1)} - \frac 1x = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac x2 - \frac{x^2}3 + \frac{x^3}4 - \cdots}{x - \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}3 - \cdots} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac 12 - \frac{x}3 + \frac{x^2}4 - \cdots}{1 - \frac{x}2 + \frac{x^2}3 - \cdots} = \frac 12.
$$
Note : you don't need the whole series expansion, you could approximate to the second term using Taylor's theorem. But I guess that falls into your "big-O notation" category of proofs.

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a series expansion to calculate the limit. The Maclaurin series (verify this for yourself) of 
$$\frac{1}{\ln(x+1)} = \frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{12} +\frac{x^2}{24} + \frac{19x^3}{720} + \cdots$$
Now place that series expansion in your limit and you see that all the limit will be $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Isn't this somewhat reliant on 'o' notation?

Comment: You mean the Laurent series. The MacLaurin series doesn't exist in this case since the function is not even defined at $0$. And still, I don't think this is really a nice argument the way you put it for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It is bit difficult to avoid LHR or series expansions here. I present here a technique which is almost like using series expansion, but a bit simpler conceptually. For this purpose I need to use the standard definition of $\log x$ as $\int_{1}^{x}(1/t)\,dt$.

Let us assume that $0 < t < 1$. Then it can be checked using algebra that $$1 - t < \frac{1}{1 + t} < 1 - t + t^{2}$$ If $0 < x < 1$ then upon integrating above inequality in the interval $[0, x]$ we get $$x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} < \log (1 + x) < x - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + \frac{x^{3}}{3}$$ or $$\dfrac{1}{x - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + \dfrac{x^{3}}{3}} < \dfrac{1}{\log(1 + x)} < \dfrac{1}{x - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}}$$ or $$\frac{6}{6x - 3x^{2} + 2x^{3}} < \frac{1}{\log(1 + x)} < \frac{2}{2x - x^{2}}$$ Subtracting $(1/x)$ from each term in above inequality we get (after some simplification) $$\frac{3 - 2x}{6 - 3x + 2x^{2}} < \frac{1}{\log(1 + x)} - \frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{2 - x}$$ Taking limits as $x \to 0^{+}$ and using Squeeze theorem we get $$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\log(1 + x)} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{2}$$ To handle the case when $x \to 0^{-}$ we need to substitute $x = -y$ to get $$\frac{1}{\log(1 + x)} - \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{\log(1 - y)} + \frac{1}{y}$$ and $y \to 0^{+}$.

Next we can see that if $0 < y < 1$ then $$\log(1 - y) = \log(1 - y^{2}) - \log(1 + y)$$ Using $\log(1 - y^{2}) < -y^{2}$ and $\log(1 + y) > y - (y^{2}/2)$ we can see that $$\log(1 - y) < -y - \frac{y^{2}}{2}$$ or $$\log(1 - y) + y < -\frac{y^{2}}{2}\,\,\,\cdots (1)$$ Again we can see that $$\frac{y^{2}}{y^{2} - 1} < \log(1 - y^{2})$$ and $$\log (1 + y) < y - \frac{y^{2}}{2} + \frac{y^{3}}{3}$$ so that $$\log(1 - y) > \frac{y^{2}}{y^{2} - 1} - y + \frac{y^{2}}{2} - \frac{y^{3}}{3}$$ or $$\frac{y^{2}}{y^{2} - 1} + \frac{y^{2}}{2} - \frac{y^{3}}{3} < \log(1 - y) + y \,\,\,\cdots (2)$$ From the equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can see that $$\frac{1}{y^{2} - 1} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{y}{3} < \frac{\log(1 - y) + y}{y^{2}} < -\frac{1}{2}$$ Taking limits as $y \to 0^{+}$ and using Squeeze theorem we get $$\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\log(1 - y) + y}{y^{2}} = -\frac{1}{2}$$ It is now easy to observe that

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\log(1 - y)} + \frac{1}{y} &= \lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\frac{\log(1 - y) + y}{y\log(1 - y)}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log(1 - y) + y}{-y^{2}\cdot\dfrac{\log(1 - y)}{-y}}\\
&= \lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log(1 - y) + y}{-y^{2}\cdot 1}\\
&= -\lim_{y \to 0^{+}}\dfrac{\log(1 - y) + y}{y^{2}}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\end{aligned}$

The above derivation is bit lengthy because it establishes the inequalities satisfied by $\log (1 + x)$ function using integration and their extensions to negative values of $x = -y$ by further algebraic manipulation. This method is the conceptually simpler (but taking more space and calculations) equivalent of using the Taylor's expansion $\log(1 + x) = x - x^{2}/2 + x^{3}/3 - \cdots$ In my view it is better to use the Taylor's expansion or LHR for such problems. However even when we apply Taylor or LHR it is better to change the problem into a different form as follows:

$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{\log(1 + x)} - \frac{1}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x - \log(1 + x)}{x\log(1 + x)}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x - \log(1 + x)}{x^{2}\cdot\dfrac{\log(1 + x)}{x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x - \log(1 + x)}{x^{2}\cdot 1}\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{x - \log(1 + x)}{x^{2}}\\\end{aligned}$

Doing this above simplification avoids taking reciprocal of a series (if you use Taylor's expansion) and also avoids complicated differentiation (if you use LHR).

Comment: I was also trying to pull that off... but the issue that I hate about this approach is that to find the bounds associated to the technique, it is most useful to know the series expansion of the function in the middle. So you seem to avoid the problem but morally you don't. Either way, I'm really really happy to have seen this answer because I think this is the only one OP can actually use, I'm not really sure he/she can use mine. +1, good job

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Fully agree with you. This is the best one can do without LHR or series expansion. I believe that there are some problems for which there is no simple solution without LHR or series. This problem happens to be of that kind. You may be able to avoid LHR stuff in some cases, but you will have to work a lot more to achieve the answer.

Comment: I mean, LHR is a fancy way of avoiding series expansions. The reason why LHR works is because of Taylor's theorem.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: I believe that the standard limit theorems like $\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ deal with problems of first order of $x$. By differentiating (in LHR) you effectively reduce the order of $x$ ($(x^{n})' = nx^{n - 1}$) and effectively in the final step use the standard limits of first order. In case of series expansion we can exactly see which order terms are canceling and which are left. That way if one is comfortable with series manipulation (like inverting a series, multiplying etc) then it becomes the easiest approach to most complex limit problems.